# How do I compile this github project?

Tags: c#, github

https://github.com/Deadpoolweid/HuReD

Does anyone know how I get that to run? I'm pretty sure I need to compile it with something but I just don't know what or how.

Comment: Please tell us what you have done and what the errors are.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! This is a C# project containing Microsoft Visual Studio project files. Clone it and open the contained `.sln` solution file using MS Visual Studio and build from within the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

You compile C# projects usually by opening them in [Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/) and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to build them.

Comment: It's F5 to build by default

Comment: @HZStudio F5 debugs the solution, what I meant was actuall `CTRL+SHIFT+B`. Updated the answer.

Comment: Great :) F5 is for starting the project

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already, get a copy of Visual Studio from the Microsoft Site and make sure the `.NET desktop development` workload is checked.

The Solution File for this repository is located at `./Hured/Hured.sln`.  Double click the `sln` file and let it load. The green play arrow on the top toolbar will compile and run the app.

You'll then find all the built files under the `bin` directory of each project.